# Store CSS color values in DB

Tags: mysql, types, sqldatatypes

I need to store a **CSS HEX** color value (`#FFFFFF` for example) into a mysql database.

Which type of data would I use and why it would be better over using another one?

Comment: You have worded this like an exam question. _Which type of data would I use and why it would be better of using another one?_

Answer (score 30, accepted):

save the color with a `char(6)` without the `#` if the column is not null... if the column is nullable use a varchar(6) to saving size

Answer (score 20):

*If you care about disk space, you should use `BINARY(3)`*

This answer is for advanced usage, and won't be relevant to most devs (the accepted answer is good). 
I'm posting here because this is the first result on Google.

There's a trade off between maintainability and disk space. A colour represented by css hex i.e. `#f8f8f8` can also be represented as `BINARY(3)`

The difficulty with `BINARY(3)` is that you have to convert the hex strings back and forth to binary. You can do this with HEX() and UNHEX() but anyone maintaining your database will need to learn about binary types if they want to make changes. It's easy to underestimate the problem this will cause for future devs.

However there are benifits to using `BINARY(3)`. The data saved to the disk for `#f8f8f8` if saved as `CHAR(6)` is `101010101011100011010001110101001001111111110` where as if it is saved as `BINARY(3)` it'll be `111110001111100011111000`

Comment: Thanks for keeping the internet up to date! we need more people like you.